# Xcode log message "flock failed to lock list file"

Tags: swift, xcode, macos

I am getting this message logged when running a freshly created macOS app in Xcode (Apple Silicon / Xcode 12).

> flock failed to lock list file ([project_path]/com.apple.metal/16777235_322/functions.list): errno = 35

What does it mean? How do I get rid of it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error message `flock failed to lock maps file: errno = 35` or (list) means that the call to `flock()` failed with error code 35, which corresponds to **EAGAIN** on some systems, on macOS as well. This error can occur if the lock to a file is held by another process, or if the process has reached its maximum number of locks.

a typical symptom is that this error message appears multiple times in your log. Which also points to a possible reason why it even came so far. But that is another talk about the inner workings of flock().

To debug this issue, you can start by trying to determine which process is holding the lock. In Terminal you can use the `lsof` command to list all open files and the processes that have them open. For example:

```bash
$ lsof | grep maps
```

This will take some seconds and give you a list of processes that have a maps file open, in other words who holds a lock on a map/list. From this list, you can try to determine which process is holding the lock by using the process ID (PID) with the flock command. For example:

```bash
$ flock -x -w 10 /proc/<PID>/maps
```

If the flock command succeeds, then the process holding the lock has released it. If the flock command fails, you can try to kill the process that is holding the lock.

nice one, but how to find the PID? More on that below.

So the following could be called *brutal* approach:

If you coded stuff with [`flock()`](https://lzone.de/cheat-sheet/Locking) in example in C (and is also the case when you do stuff with `pipe` mechanism because this might interfere with /dev/null which is a a special case of a file and use `fork()`, `dup()`, `dup2()`, `shmget()` and like-like calls) and somehow your locking/unlocking mechanism messed up your maps, which is the place where the locks are written to then certainly `pkill` will help you out. But before doing so, proof that there are multiple processes with the same name - you will know what the name should look like because you coded it yourself.

In case you know the name you can just use `pgrep` to find all instances.

```
pgrep -x myappname
```

the myappname was for sure in the maps list? If yes, go on, this command above will print a list of PID which correspond to this process name which corresponds to the app name usually.

From here you could, in this is why i named it *brutal*, just `pkill` all of them with

```
pkill -x myappname
```

Of course this will force all of them to quit immediately. Which in turn should also release the locks onto files they might still hold. But beware pkill-ing does not properly deallocate, it just immediately exits and so a coded flock unlock in a -dealloc method would also not fire but the used memory gets free'd - which is what you need.

*Why does it happen at all? Well you might have just crashed your app in development or Metal debugging was turned which of course uses this mechanism as well in example for piping logs. When you exit without properly dealloc or similar then there might be no cleanup process invoked which could release the **File-lock** (short: flock) to some file or pipe, ergo the file stays locked.*

And as Xcode with Metal debugging will try to set a lock to its maps file but the file is locked as left over from a crash before you get this error message for each attempt to set a lock on a locked file. So it makes no sense just to turn off Metal debugging, if that was the reason, you would still need to unlock the file still in use by a Zombie-app/process. Erasing the maps file yourself is like messing with the file system directly and can of course result in surprises.

also

```
df -l
```

should give you a list of your filesystem with usage informations where you can read how much is used up. In the case of 100% use of /dev/null and similar you can see if you messed up shared memory in which case flock to unlock a file will also fail when you attempt to acquire some file on a used up memory. If that all happened by using a pipe mechanism you very likely did not flush your buffer *aka* you did not read from it which in turn should empty such buffer so it can't lock in case it became full.

if all that did not help -  your last resort is restarting the machine.

Answer (score 8):

This happens when the application is already running, or could not exit gracefully and continues to run in the background.

Try:

```
$ pkill <yourappname>
```

Answer (score 0):

It would usually point to a file with list. Delete it and you should be good.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).